# Count first three integers from a file that contains multiple 30 digit numbers, count the first 3 integers on every line and output the sum

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

How may I Extract first three integers from a large file with multiple 30 digit length integers and output the sum of those first three digits. In Linux terminal?

Comment: A couple of questions about the file format:  Are there multiple 30-digit numbers per line of the file, or just one number per line?  Do you want to sum the first three 30-digit numbers in the file, or, as you wrote, the first three  _digits_ (presumably of the first 30-digit number)?

Comment: Example from the source and expected output can be helpful.

Comment: 30 digit integer number would require at least 100 bit, I am not sure regular awk can handle this, you will need something like R or sage math.

Comment: It would be very useful to [see a few lines of such a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/711423/edit), along with your expected output for the sample.

Comment: Should your first use of the word _integer_ actually mean _digit_?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by `integers` you mean `digits` and that the first 3 characters in each line are always digits:

```
awk '{sum+=substr($0,1,3)} END{print sum+0}' file
```

Comment: It seems to me the OP wants to sum up three 30-digits numbers per line, not extract the first 3 digits of each line and sum them up.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I disagree since they say `output the sum of those first three digits` but I guess we'll find out once the OP adds sample input/output.

Comment: I, too, assume the use of _digits_ in the next to last sentence of the question was a typo and the OP intended to write `the sum of the first three integers`.

Comment: Let's wait and see if the OP answers the questions seeking clarity on this. Otherwise I'd VTC as unclear

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -Mbigint -MList::Util=sum -lne '
  print sum(0, (/(?<!\d)\d{30}(?!\d)/g)[0..2])' < your-file
```

Would locate the first 3 sequences of exactly 30 decimal digits not surrounded by more digits, sum them up and output the result.

If there are fewer than 3 numbers on a line, the sum is performed with as many as there are. If you only want the result for lines that have at least 3 of those numbers, change it to:

```
perl -Mbigint -MList::Util=sum -lne '
  @numbers = /(?<!\d)\d{30}(?!\d)/g;
  print sum(0, @numbers[0..2]) if @numbers >= 3
  ' < your-file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -e 'my @a; repeat {get.match(:global, /\d**30/) ??  @a.push(~$/) !! next} until @a.elems == 3; @a.sum.put'   30_digits.txt
```

Sample Input:

```
~$ raku -e 'for ^3 { put ([0..9].roll xx 30).join};' > 30_digits.txt
~$ cat 30_digits.txt
785624076726806242935676754394
801557051570803235347163971795
620594508808581496037051947969
```

Sample Output:

```
2207775637106190974319892674158
```

This answer in Raku will read the first three 30-digit numbers, and sum them. With the `:global` 'adverb' (i.e. parameter), it doesn't matter which line the 30-digit numbers come from. Without the `:global` 'adverb', Raku will take the ***first*** 30-digit number it encounters on each line, and sums three such numbers.

The Raku code above only includes a 'bare-bones' Regex, and of course, since regexes read left-to-right, numbers longer than 30 digits in length will be truncated on the right end. You certainly can improve matching by including a (right-side) field delimiter, such as a comma in the case of a CSV file. A general Regex to try if you have recognition issues might be:

```
/ \D? \d**30 \D /
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes
https://raku.org